# How to safely run user-supplied PHP code

Tags: php, security, eval

I'm building an online teaching tool in which users submit their own sub-classes of a PHP class which I ask them to extend.

My plan is to have users upload their code as a string (which is a class definition) and then at some point run it with `eval()`.

I want to know if there is a way to do this safely, so that the untrusted code can't do malicious things to my server environment. I am NOT looking for a complicated virtualization solution involving containers or multiple servers... my app needs to be pretty portable. I'm hoping that there is either a built-in PHP method for limiting what certain code can do, or maybe there's an established pattern for how to "validate" / "sanitize" the code. I've done stuff like this with HTML, where it's pretty easy to filter out things like `<script>` but I'm not sure there's an analogue for backend languages like PHP.

Update:
Based on links in the comments, it sounds like PHP's Runkit is the kind of thing I'm looking for. If someone has a minimal example for how to use it (or something similar) that should answer my question nicely.

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=php+codepad pick one\

Comment: @nogad Most of those look highly insecure. "Work in progress", "don't run on a live server", "local development only", etc. in the first couple I spot-checked.

Comment: This really is off topic, but I would suggest reaching out to sjon, the [creator of 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/about). That site probably does exactly what you want

Comment: @nogad why do you think this question should be closed?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234101/how-to-safely-execute-user-submitted-php-code